# What is a state of an object after it was moved-from via a reference to its base class?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Assume, there is a hierarchy of two classes:

```
class Base {};
class Foo: public Base {};
```

Which are used like this:

```
Foo foo;
Base &base = foo;
Base moved = std::move(base);
```

In what state is `foo` after such move? Does the Standard impose any requirements on limitations on such code?

Comment: Since there are no virtual functions in both classes, the move constructor of the base will be used.

Comment: Yes, it is about the state of `foo`. Thanks!

Comment: The standard does not impose any requirements on what your classes should do, moved or otherwise. But note that, despite the call to `move`, nothing in your code moves anything. Your class has no data members, so there is nothing to move. If there was something to move, the result of moving an object would be determined by what your move constructor and move assignment operator do.

Comment: In this specific case nothing would happen with `foo` since neither its class nor its base class have any members. The [implicitly defined move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-defined_move_constructor) simply would do nothing.

Comment: @OutOfBound -- even if the class had virtual functions, the move constructor of the base would be used. That last line creates a `Base` object.

Comment: @PeteBecker, yes, in this case nothing will happen. The question is more theoretical: what _should_ happen to `foo` if it had data members etc.

Comment: @Kane Your question isn't phrased liked that. If you derive from standard objects, the result is mostly: *The object is left in a valid but unspecified state*.

Comment: @Kane -- as I said, what will happen is whatever your move constructor or move assignment operator do. There's no magic here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, so, after moving from `base`, `foo` also should end up in a valid but otherwise unspecified state and must be treated _as if_ it was moved-from `foo`? I wonder if this is written anywhere or is it just a common sense.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- the specification talks about the properties of classes defined in the C++ standard. It does not constrain user-defined classes. If somebody wants to write a class that's utterly useless after a move, that's up to them. Unlike classes defined by the standard, such a class simply could not be used after being moved from. That's probably a dumb idea, but it doesn't run afoul of the C++ specification.

Comment: @Kane - It's as much common sense as the 0/3/5 rule. You don't *have* to follow it, but your program will suffer.

Comment: @Kane -- the C++ standard doesn't say anything about what your move constructor or move assignment operator should do to the object being moved from. If you want to write a move constructor that leaves the moved-from object in a state that will blow up if you touch it, that's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard does not make any such requirement on move constructors for C++ classes that are not a part of the standard library.  The library writer is free to do what they want.  For components that are a part of the standard library, the C++17 standard does say something (emphasis mine)

**§ 20.5.5.15 Moved-from state of library types [lib.types.movedfrom]**

> Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from (15.8). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. **Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.**

For classes in the standard library that are a part of an inheritance hierarchy, you would have to consult the documentation to see what happens when you try and move construct a base object from a base class rvalue reference a derived class object.  So if you could specify which class in particular you were worried about I could try and help more.

---

Not sure how relevant this is to your question, but regarding what would really happen in such a constructor.  Remember that the virtual function mechanism is disabled in constructors for the object that is going to be constructed,  but *not* for the referenced object.  In the following example

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual vector<int> extract_vector() { ... }

    // Move constructor can use virtual functions on the other object
    Base(Base&& other) {
        this->vec = other.extract_vector();
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> vec;
};

class Foo : public Base {
public:
    vector<int> extract_vector() override { ... }

private:
    // this does something ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ 
    SpecialVectorAdaptor<std::vector<int>> vec;
};
```

The virtual function `extract_vector` on `other` in the move constructor for `Base` will be called, and you can utilize virtual methods on the `other` object.  But you cannot use any such virtual methods on the class that is going to be constructed.

---

**So long story short**, the behavior of the code you have shown will depend strictly on the implementation of the classes in question.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, nothing happens, since both `Base` and `Foo` are empty classes.

For the more interesting situation that both `Base` and `Foo` have some movable members (or bases), since `Base` has no user-defined move constructor, the default move constructor will be used. **This will move the `Base` part of `foo` to `moved`, but leave the rest intact.** For example, after

```
struct Base      { std::unique_ptr<int> X; };
struct Foo: Base { std::unique_ptr<int> Y; };

Foo foo;
foo.X.reset(new int);
foo.Y.reset(new int);
Base &base = foo;
Base moved = std::move(base);
```

`foo.X` is empty (`nullptr`) with the original value moved to `moved`, but still `foo.Y` still holds the initial value.

This demonstrates that when moving from a reference you potentially change the state of the referred to object, which can create all sorts of unwanted effects and is best avoided.